# List of past commands used in the shell

Tags: command-line

How can I easily see a list of commands I recently entered in the shell? Instead of going up

Comment: More information: http://askubuntu.com/questions/379225/does-the-terminal-store-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below command,

```
history
```

```
 NAME
       history - GNU History Library

COPYRIGHT
       The GNU History Library is Copyright (C) 1989-2011 by the Free Software
       Foundation, Inc.

DESCRIPTION
       Many programs read input from the user a line at a time.  The GNU  His‐
       tory  library is able to keep track of those lines, associate arbitrary
       data with each line, and utilize information  from  previous  lines  in
       composing new ones.
```

Run `man history` command for more details.

Comment: Awesome that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

`history | less` --> view/scroll up/down the command executed list

`history | tail -f` --> last 10 executed commands

if you want to get the execution timestamp of commands, export following environment variable

`HISTTIMEFORMAT=" %F %T "` (Helpful to trace timestamp of command, filtering)